# iPhone: NSAttributedString

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to concat two NSAttributedString ? Or NSAttributedString and NSString ?
I tried something like this:

```
NSAttributedString *attr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...%@", attributedString];
NSLog (@"%@", [attr string]);
```

But thats not work...Any suggestions ? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the NSAttributedString contains information not related to the string, you can't just append it to an NSString without losing information.

To change the NSAttributedString using the NSString, you need to make a mutable copy of the NSAttributedString and use the editing methods on the resulting NSMutableAttributedString.

Answer (score 8):

Convert one (e.g., your attributedString) to NSMutableAttributedString and then append the other (e.g., attributedString2) using appendAttributedString:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *resultString = [attributedString mutableCopy];
[resultString appendAttributedString:attributedString2];
```

The concatenated string is in resultString.

Answer (score 1):

1. cat the strings
2. create the new attributed string
3. apply the attributes to the appropriate ranges

or you could simply use `-[NSMutableAttributedString insertAttributedString:atIndex:]`

Comment: Does that NSMutableString method actually exist? I can't find it in the documentation and XCode can't find it either :)

Comment: thanks, Joachim. it's an im of `NSMutableAttributedString`. updated.